# Symfony2 with sofort.com payment

Tags: symfony

I am working on a symfony 2 project where the user should be able to use payments via PayPal and Sofort.com.

Yet i have implemented paypal payments which i managed successfully. 
But i am stuck with sofort.com. I have searched the web for tutorials but i can hardly find anything. 
I've read through their API and integrated their PHP SDK. But i dont get how get on.Maybe someone here has worked with it, and can help me out what to do next. 
That would be really cool

Can somebody help me point in the right direction with it? i would be really thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download the Sofort SDK from their website which is [here](https://www.sofort.com/integrationCenter-ger-DE/content/download/10359/248895/file/SofortLib-PHP-2.2.1.zip).

Then in their example folder you'll find two files: example.sofortueberweisung.php and example.transaction.php.

The example.sofortueberweisung.php shows you how redirect the user with specific values to the payment page.

The example.transaction.php shows what to do in the notify action.

After the payment is completed the user will be send to the success link.
Sofort sends transaction data to the notify action which you can process.

If the user aborts the payment he or she will be forwarded to the abort link.

Its so super easy to implement it, i think imo its much easier then paypal.

Hope it helps people out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Omnipay](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/) library from [ThePHPLeague](http://thephpleague.com/), which provides a common interface to easily create a custom gateways. Also [there is a symfony2 bundle](https://github.com/xola/OmnipayBundle) which provides a wrapper for that library.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i called the customer service today and they told me how to do stuff.Now it works just fine :)

Comment: @Sharpy35 Fine, post you solution then, It can be useful to others.